# Jquery: Dynamic binding events on a Highcharts object

Tags: highcharts, jquery

I'm trying to use, but to no luck

```
$("parent").on("click","child",function(){
  //
}
```

My HTML sits this way

```
<ul id="carouselRoot">
    <li id="container0"><div class="highcharts-container">.....</li>
    <li>
        <ul id="subCarousel">
             <li id="container1"><div class="highcharts-container">.....</li>
             <li id="container2"><div class="highcharts-container">.....</li>
             <li id="container3"><div class="highcharts-container">.....</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to capture the click event on each chart. So, $(".highcharts-container").click() works fine but I'm also adding charts dynamically to #subCarousel.

and doing

```
$("#subCarousel li").on("click",".highcharts-container",function(){});
```

simply does not invoke the call. How do I get around this?

PS: I've also tried using body as the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Highchart API for capturing the click

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    alert ('clicked');
                }
            }        
        }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/)**

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code within `$(document).ready(function(){.....})`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#subCarousel li").on("click",".highcharts-container",function(){
        alert('fgfg');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/CGB3J/1/)

Comment: Yeah, no luck with that. The problem actually is in the highcharts-container element which simply refuses to propagate the click event to its parent..

Answer (score -1):

Use highcharts built-in events. But for custom events, install [highcharts-custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events).